# How can I prevent this kind of logic error? (var x changes between its value is copied to another var y and the use of var y, so that y is outdated)

Tags: swift, lint, cs193p

Summary:

I made a mistake in my Swift code and I've fixed it. Then I asked myself why this happened and how I could avoid it. I tried some ways but nothing helps.

I put the mistake and my thinking below. I hope you could teach me the right method to avoid this kind of mistake, but any idea, hint, or suggestion would be appreciated.

---

How can I avoid this kind of logic error?

The following is an excerpt from my assignment for Stanford cs193p course.

```
class SomeClass {

    ...

    var accumulator: Double?

    func someFunc() {
        // I use `localAccumulator` and write `self.` for clarity.
        if let localAccumulator = self.accumulator { // A
            // `self.accumulator` is modified in this method
            performPendingBinaryOperation() // B
            pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(firstOperand: localAccumulator) // C
        }
    }

    private func performPendingBinaryOperation() {
        accumulator = pendingBinaryOperation.perform(with: accumulator)
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem here is that the line B has changed the value of instance value `self.accumulator`, and the line C should use the new value stored in `self.accumulator`, but it uses the **outdated** local var `localAccumulator` which was copied from `self.accumulator`'s old value.

It was easy to find out the logic error via debugger. But then I reflected on my mistake, and was trying to look for a method to avoid this kind of logic error.

Method 1: use nil checking rather than optional binding

```
if self.accumulator != nil { // A
    // `self.accumulator` is modified in this method
    performPendingBinaryOperation() // B
    pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(firstOperand: self.accumulator!) // C
}
```

Actually, what really matters here is the force unwrapped `self.accumulator!`, it ensures the value comes from the real source. Using nil checking rather than optional binding can force me to force unwrap on `self.accumulator`.

But in some Swift style guides(GitHub, RayWenderlich, LinkedIn), force unwrapping is not encouraged. They prefer optional binding.

Method 2: use assertions.

```
if localAccumulator = self.accumulator { // A
    // `self.accumulator` is modified in this method
    performPendingBinaryOperation() // B
    assert(localAccumulator == self.accumulator) // D
    pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(firstOperand: localAccumulator) // C
}
```

I insert a assertion to check whether the `localAccumulator` is still equal to `self.accumulator`. This works, it will stop running once `self.accumulator` is modified unexpectedly. But it's so easy to forget to add this assertion line.

Method 3: [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)

To find a way to detect this kind of error, I've skimmed SwiftLint's all rules, and also got a basic understanding of
[SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten)(one of SwiftLint's dependencies). It seems too complicated to detect this kind of error by SwiftLint, especially when I make this pattern more general.

Some similar cases

Case 1: guard optional binding

```
func someFunc() {
    guard let localAccumulator = self.accumulator { // A
        return
    }
    // `self.accumulator` is modified in this method
    performPendingBinaryOperation() // B
    pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(firstOperand: localAccumulator) // C
}
```

In this case, it's much more difficult for human to notice the error, because `localAccumulator` has a broader scope with guard optional binding than if optional binding.

Case 2: value copy caused by function passing parameters

```
// Assume that this function will be called somewhere else with `self.accumulator` as its argument, like `someFunc(self.accumulator)`
func someFunc(_ localAccumulator) {
    // `self.accumulator` is modified in this method
    performPendingBinaryOperation() // B
    pendingBinaryOperation = PendingBinaryOperation(firstOperand: localAccumulator) // C
}
```

In this case, `localAccumulator` copies from `self.accumulator` when this function is called, then `self.accumulator` changes in the line B, the line C expects the `self.accumulator`'s new value, but get its old value from `localAccumulator`.

In fact, the basic pattern is as below,

```
var x = oldValue
let y = x
functionChangingX() // assign x newValue
functionExpectingX(y) // expecting y is newValue, but it's oldValue
```

`x` ~ `self.accumulator`

`y` ~ `localAccumulator`

`functionChangingX` ~ `performPendingBinaryOperation`

`functionExpectingX` ~ `PendingBinaryOperation.init`

This error pattern looks like so common that I guess there should be a name for this error pattern.

Anyway, back to my question, how can I avoid this kind of logic error?

Answer (score 0):

This example shows what I understood from your problem:

```swift
var name: String? = "Mike"

func doSomething() {

    // Check if "name" is set (not nil)
    if let personName = name {

        addLastNameToGlobalName() // modifies global var "name"

        // 
        // Here, you want to use the updated "name" value. As you mention, at this point, 
        // "name" could/might/should be different than "personName" (it could
        // even be nil).
        // 
        greet(person: ???) // use "name"? (which is optional), "personName"?, or what?

    }
}
```

To me, the general approach is the problem here. The fact that you are:

1. Checking that a global optional-value is not nil
2. Calling a function that alters this global optional-value
3. Wanting to use the updated global optional-value as a non-optional value

A simple change in the approach/design of greeting this person would allow you to avoid the type of "logic error" that you mention.

Example 1:

```swift
var name: String? = "Mike"

func doSomething() {

    // Check if "name" is set (not nil)
    if let personName = name {
        greet(person: fullName(for: personName))
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```swift
var name: String? = "Mike"

func doSomething() {

    // Check if "name" is set (not nil)
    if let personName = name {
        let fullName = addLastNameToGlobalName() // modifies global var "name" and returns the new value
        greet(person: fullName) 
    }
}
```